# Выборочное удаление строк из файла Python

Tags: python

[image: так это выглядит в командной строке]Итак, я хочу создать адресную книгу. Когда пользователь нажимает "2" выводится список всех контактов книги, пронумерованный. Я хочу, чтобы далее пользователь из командной строки мог как-то удалить выбранный им контакт(для этого я их и пронумеровал)  , в самом файле контакты не пронумерованы, они нумеруются прямо перед выводом

```
ab = {  "Мама" : "8908783xx07",
        "Папа" : "8908783xr07"
}



print("Выберите действие:")
print("1)Добавить контакт")
print("2)Удалить контакт")
print("3)Просмотреть список всех контактов")
print("4)Изменить контакт")
print("5)Найти контакт")

act = input("Действие: ")

#События 2

if act == "2":
    i = 0
    f = open("ab1.txt")
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if len(line) == 0:
            break
        i = i + 1
        print(i, ")", line, end="")
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите файл `ab1.txt` в вопрос (хотя бы частично). Вы можете сделать это, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: не понял вас, к сожалению

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы пользователь мог удалить контакт (строку) из файла, я правильно понимаю? Для этого нужно написать код. Но мы не знаем, как именно Вы храните контакты в файле, а точнее как контакты в нём пронумерованы. Хочется увидеть пример содержимого `ab1.txt`.

Comment: добавил картинку

Comment: то есть в файле те же 3 контакта, только там они без номеров

Comment: сорри если непонятно, я новичок)

Comment: А что делать с нумерацией после удаления строки? Придётся перезаписывать все последующие строки? Предположим, я удалю вторую, нумерация станет `1, 3`. Так и оставить? Вообще советую Вам перейти на простенькую БД (например, `SQLite`).

Comment: я только начал изучать питон, и я вообще не знаю пока такого)это было задание в книге Byte of Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте

```
with open('in.txt') as inp:
    list=inp.read().split() # или massiv=[int(i) for i in inp.read().split()] элемент будет число тип int
print(list)
```

это отправит каждую строку вашего файла в ячейку списка.
Далее пользователь вводит номер строки, которую нужно удалить, допустим, a.
Пишете `del list[a-1]` (-1 потому что индекс в массиве на 1 меньше его номера)
И просто перезаписываете файл контактов